# Does recursive function print in reverse?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void convertToBinary(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n>0)
    {
        convertToBinary(n / 2);
        cout << n % 2;
    }
}
int main(){
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    convertToBinary(n);

}
```

Here is a function recursion that coverts from decimal to binary, for example If I give this function n equals to `10` the output is `1010`, How come 1 is at the rightmost digit? It would be `0` since 10 % 2 = `0`, then print `0` , so the expected output would be 101, since there's leading a `0`.

Comment: You have to follow the flow of execution of the program in debugger or manually using pencil and paper. As the saying goes, "To understand recursion, you have to understand recursion first."

Comment: Try changing the order of `convertToBinary(n / 2);` and `cout << n % 2;` and see what is different.

Comment: 8 is 1000, not 1010. It appears you have other bugs too. A complete reversal would have printed 0001.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Sorry, edited

Comment: You can think this way. Before output of `10 % 2` you called `convertToBinary(5)`. Before output of `5 % 2`, you called `convertToBinary(2)`. And so on. So the first output function is `convertToBinary(1)` then `convertToBinary(2)` then `convertToBinary(5)` then `convertToBinary(10)`

Comment: @Daniel1147 How are these data stored?

Comment: @JoeCole How is the currently executing point in any program stored?

Comment: In function `convertToBinary` you don't store your data. You just print `n % 2` to the output.

Comment: Your code works on my end fine :(. What compiler what OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but the binary representation of decimal 10 is b'1010... b'101 represent decimal 5. So the code is working correctly: You're mistaking in your train of thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure used by recursive calls is called as [stack](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/stack-data-structure). Its working principle is last-in-first-out. So, not until your base condition i.e. `(n > 0)` is satisfied, `convertToBinary` re-cursively call before printing `n%2` itself. When the base condition isn't fulfilled, `convertToBinary` commences to print binary values inversely because of stack structure.