# Issue with recursion in C++

Tags: c++

Why is it not counting properly? I'm so confused why is it printing the string with 0's in it? I just want to count the number of uppercase letters and output them.

```
#include <iostream>

void uppercase(const char *str){
    //std::vector<char> strVector;
    int counter = 0;
    if(str[0]){
        if(isupper(str[0])) counter++;
        uppercase(str+1);
    }
     std::cout<<counter;
}
int main(){
   uppercase("United States of America");

}
```

the output:

```
0000000100000000010000001
```

Comment: Since you are printing counter at the very last i.e. after recursion , it is printing in reverse order

Comment: Declare counter variable outside the function or pass it as argument and then print it in Main

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083724/does-recursive-function-print-in-reverse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [question on c++ recursion and local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852237/question-on-c-recursion-and-local-variables)

Comment: Solving this is much simpler if you do it iteratively. Recursion is a powerful tool for analysis, but almost always a disaster for implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue in your function is that you are printing out whether a `char` is uppercase or not. Instead, you should make the function return an `int`, and recursively call the function with the next substring:

```
int uppercase(const char *str) {
    if(str[0]) {                    // while not reached the end of the string 
        return !! isupper(str[0])   // add 1 if uppercase 
               + uppercase(str+1);  // recursively call with suffix of string
    }
    return 0;  // base case
}
```

and now you can simply print the returned result:

```
int main(){
  std::cout << uppercase("United States of America");
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mdzfj7).

Note that the `!!` is just a shorter syntax that converts the result if `isupper` to a `bool` and then back to an `int`. This is equivalent to `isupper(str[0]) ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation function should be doing just that: *calculating* (i.e. *not* printing *anything*). Instead, it should return the number and have the original caller take the final step of printing.

E.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int uppercase(const char *str)
{
    if (*str) 
        return (isupper(*str) ? 1 : 0) + uppercase(str+1);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << uppercase("United States of America") << '\n';
}
```